# GDB throws error on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gdb

When I try stepping through a program, gdb throws this error

```
std::ostream::operator<< (this=0x6013c0 <std::cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, __n=2)
at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc:110
110     /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc: No such file or directory.
```

This is the program I am trying to debug.

```
#include <iostream>

int printPrime(int, int);

int main()
{
    int t, c;
    std::cin >> t;
    c = t;
    int m[t], n[t];
    while (t--) {
        std::cin >> m[t] >> n[t];
    }
    while (c--) {
        printPrime(m[c], n[c]);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int printPrime(int m, int n)
{
    do {
        int c = m;
        int lim = c>>2;
        if (c <= 1)  continue;
        while (c-- && c>lim) {
            if (m%c == 0) {
                if (c == 1) {
                    std::cout << m << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    } while(m++ && m<=n);
}
```

There is no problem with the program code as it runs correctly. I guess it is a problem with my install of GDB on Arch. The error is shown when it encounters `cin` or `cout`.

This error doesn't show when I tried running it in my Ubuntu VM

Comment: Same problem here : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199587

Comment: Is it a problem with my installation and paths or is it with GDB or GCC?
Is there any solution or temporary fix that you know of?

Comment: It's a problem with the standard install. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've filled a bug report against this issue: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47220

This happens because the ostream source file cannot be found.

## Workaround 1

You can [strip](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strip.html) the libstdc++ library:

```
sudo strip /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

And then gdb will not try to open the source file and the error will not appear anymore.

You can switch back to the unstripped version by reinstalling it with:

```
sudo pacman -S gcc-libs
```

## Workaround 2

You can add a [substitution rule](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) in gdb:

```
gdb tst
(gdb) set substitute-path /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include /usr/include/c++/5.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

2017 Update -
Note you can now in `launch.json`

```
"setupCommands": [
  {
    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
    "ignoreFailures": true
  },
  {
    "text": "set substitute-path /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include /usr/include/c++/7.2.0"
  }
 ],
```